# Forward Euler PDE (grid method) misunderstanding - Is the question missing a detail

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We are interested in solving the advection equation $u_t = u_x$ where $0\leq x < 1$, $t \geq 0$

with periodic boundary conditions and $u(x,0) = f(x),f(x) = f(x+1)$
In the grid $x_0,x_1,\dots x_N$, $t_0,t_1,\dots t_N$.

using the forward euler method, or $\frac{v(x_j,t_{n+1}) - v(x_j,t_n)}{\Delta t}= \frac{v(x_{j+1},t_n)-v(x_{j-1},t_n)}{2\Delta x}$ where $v$ is the approximation of $u$ at the grid points.

**What I don't understand:**

We are essentially using $v(x_{j-1},t_n), v(x_j,t_n),v(x_{j+1},t_n)$ to calculate $v(x_j,t_{n+1})$. Initially this is fine because $v(x_j,0)$ is known for all $j$, but how would we calculate $v(x_0,t_1)$? we can't, since that would require us to know $v(x_{-1}, t_0)$ which doesn't exist. And this issue propagates, each new $t_n$ we can calculate one less point than $t_{n-1}$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recurrence relation for the forward time, central space scheme is $$u_{j}^{n+1} = -\gamma u_{j-1}^{n} + u_{j}^{n} + \gamma u_{j+1}^{n}$$ where $\gamma = \Delta t/(2\Delta x)$. Writing the first few terms out (for $j=1,..,M-1$) yields

\begin{align} 
u_{1}^{n+1} &= -\gamma u_{0}^{n} + u_{1}^{n} + \gamma u_{2}^{n} \\ 
u_{2}^{n+1} &= -\gamma u_{1}^{n} + u_{2}^{n} + \gamma u_{3}^{n} \\ 
\vdots \\ 
u_{M-1}^{n+1} &= -\gamma u_{M-2}^{n} + u_{M-1}^{n} + \gamma u_{M}^{n} 
\end{align}

which we can write as a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}^{n+1} \\
u_{2}^{n+1} \\
u_{3}^{n+1} \\
\vdots \\
u_{M-1}^{n+1}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \gamma & & & \\
    -\gamma & 1 & \gamma &  \\
     & -\gamma & 1 & \gamma &  \\
    \\
     & & & -\gamma & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}^{n} \\
u_{2}^{n} \\
u_{3}^{n} \\
\vdots \\
u_{M-1}^{n}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-\gamma u_{0}^{n} \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
\gamma u_{M}^{n}
\end{pmatrix}  \tag 1$$

To answer your question 'how would we calculate $v(x_{0},t_{1})$?', periodic boundary conditions imply $u_{0}^{n} = u_{M-1}^{n}$ and $u_{1}^{n} = u_{M}^{n}$ for all $n$ (time). Therefore, we can rewrite the matrix equation $(1)$ as

$$\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}^{n+1} \\
u_{2}^{n+1} \\
u_{3}^{n+1} \\
\vdots \\
u_{M-1}^{n+1}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \gamma & & & -\gamma \\
    -\gamma & 1 & \gamma &  \\
     & -\gamma & 1 & \gamma &  \\
    \\
    \gamma & & & -\gamma & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}^{n} \\
u_{2}^{n} \\
u_{3}^{n} \\
\vdots \\
u_{M-1}^{n}
\end{pmatrix} \tag 2$$

We also know that the initial condition $u(x,0) = f(x) \implies u_{j}^{0} = f_{j}$ where $f_{j} = f(x_{j})$ is $f(x)$ evaluated at the spatial grid points $x_{j}$. So for the *first* iteration we need to solve

$$\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}^{1} \\
u_{2}^{1} \\
u_{3}^{1} \\
\vdots \\
u_{M-1}^{1}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \gamma & & & -\gamma \\
    -\gamma & 1 & \gamma &  \\
     & -\gamma & 1 & \gamma &  \\
    \\
    \gamma & & & -\gamma & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
f_{1} \\
f_{2} \\
f_{3} \\
\vdots \\
f_{M-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

and thereafter we solve $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

When you rewrite your equation

$$ \frac{v(x_{j}, t_{n+1}) -v(x_{j},t_{n}) }{\Delta t} = \frac{v(x_{j+1},t_{n}) -v(x_{j-1},t_{n})}{2 \Delta x}  \tag{1}$$

you get this

$$ v(x_{j},t_{n+1})- v(x_{j},t_{n}) =  \frac{\Delta t(v(x_{j+1},t_{n}) -v(x_{j-1},t_{n}))}{2 \Delta x} \tag{2}$$

$$ v(x_{j},t_{n+1}) =  v(x_{j},t_{n}) +  \frac{\Delta t(v(x_{j+1},t_{n}) -v(x_{j-1},t_{n}))}{2 \Delta x} \tag{3}$$

you said we have the initial condition where $t_{n} = 0$ . The grid is only between $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$ then you discretize it so $x_{j-1}$ is the first point in the array. Forward euler is the most basic runge kutte method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Why does it matter how I discretize the grid? at any rate I will have that $v(0, \Delta t) = v(0,0) + \frac{\Delta t (v(\Delta x, 0) - v(-\Delta x, 0)}{2\Delta x}$

Comment: A similar thing happens at the other boundary, $v(1, t_N)$ will require us to know $v(1+\Delta x, T_{N-1})$.

Comment: you have to define the boundary conditions the first and last points in the array are the boundaries.

Comment: you have boundary conditions.

Comment: Could you show me how you would find $v(0, \Delta t)$? As far as I understand from the question, it wasn't given to us.

Comment: give me a moment..

Comment: part of the problem is you're putting in $\Delta t$ for the function where it is $t_{n}$ that is simply $t_{1} $   it's mixing up what would be in the actual place.http://calculuslab.deltacollege.edu/ODE/7-C-1/7-C-1-h-c.html

Comment: https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/lectures/ws2016-2017/num_methods_i/advection.pdf there is a demonstration here on page 3 it's hard to write . you end up with a tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: @OriaGruber: Your problem is periodic, periodic boundary conditions give the possibility for periodic continuation of the solution. So you not only have $f(x+1)=f(x)$ but also $u(x+1,t)=u(x,1)$. Thus $u(−Δx,t)=u(1−Δx,t)$, $u(1+Δx,t)=u(Δx,t)$.