# Linear advection eqution and periodic b.c. implementation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

I want to implement the **forward in time, centered in space** scheme for the linear advection \begin{align} u_t+ a u_x=0 \end{align} with periodic boundary conditions and initial datum $u(x,0)$. I know that this scheme is unconditionally unstable and the theory about that, but my question is just on the implementation part

I'm doing this in the interval $x \in [0,1]$ and  $t \in [0,1]$.

The scheme is

\begin{align}
u_{i}^{n+1}= u_{i}^n-\frac{a dt}{2dx}(u_{i+1}^n-u_{i-1}^n)
\end{align}

Say I discretize $[0,1]$ with $M$ points. So $dx=\frac{1}{M-1}$. My main problem is the implementation of the boundary conditions. I **overlap** the nodes $x_1=0$ and $x_M=1$.

So, at the first iteration, my scheme is (I omit the time index)

\begin{align}
u_1=u_1- \frac{a dt}{2 dx} (u_2-u_0)
\end{align}

Now, since $u_0$ is not known, I would use the fact that $x_1=x_M$, and hence the point at the left of $x_1$ is $x_{M-1}$ and hence $u_0=u_{M-1}$.

Now I would solve this up to node $x_{M-1}$, so I will have

\begin{align}
u_{M-1}=u_{M-1} - \frac{a dt}{2 dx} (u_{1} - u_{M-2})
\end{align}
where I used the fact that $u_M=u_1$.

Then I will update $u_{M}=u_{1}$.

Comment: @Harry49 If my implementation of the periodic boundary conditions is right and if there's anything wrong in what I've written, since indices are making me crazy

Comment: Many thanks! @Harry49

Comment: The main problem is that I've seen different implementation, and I still don't understand how to treat the fact that $x_1=x_M$ (i.e. overlapping first and last node)

Comment: Why do you solve up to the point $x_{M-1}$? It should be $x_M$. And the point $i=M-1$, you should have $u_{M-1}=u_{M-1} - \frac{a dt}{2 dx} (u_{M} - u_{M-2})$. But the point that you interested is $i=M$, in this case: we have $u_{M}=u_{M} - \frac{a dt}{2 dx} (u_{M+1} - u_{M-1})$ but $u_{M+1} = u_{2}$

Comment: @Sesame I solve up to $M-1$ and the impose $u_M=U_1$. You're right for the expression for $u_{M-1}$, it was a typo, now I fixed it

Comment: @Sesame The main point is: you overlap the first node $x_1$ and the last node $x_M$. So $u_{M+1}=u_2$ and for $u_0=u_{M-1}$, right?

So you have $u_1=u_1 - \frac{a dt}{2 dx} (u_2-u_{M-1})$, right?

Comment: [I gave an answer to this question sometime ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960358/forward-euler-pde-grid-method-misunderstanding-is-the-question-missing-a-det/2960477#2960477).

Comment: Thanks. For what I've seen, Sesame answer is the same of yours, right? Just change the fact that you start indexing from $0$, so for you $u_0=u_{M-1}$, while for me  $u_0=u_M$. So I can say that the periodicity implies that the unknown value solution (like in this case $u_0$, since I'm outside the domain) is equal to the value at the LAST point (i.e $x_M$ for me, $x_{M-1}$ for you), right? (Then, he same argument applies for the other boundary term)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We give the following space discretization : $\forall i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$: $\{x_1=0,x_2,\dots,x_M=l\}$ (I started to count from 1 on purpose as you code in Matlab...). 
Suppose that we want to solve the above PDE by using an Euler scheme:
\begin{align}
u_{i}^{n+1}= u_{i}^n-\gamma u_{i+1}^n + \gamma u_{i-1}^n
\end{align}
where $\gamma = \frac{a dt}{2dx}$.
We impose periodic boundary conditions, i.e. $u(0,t)=u(l,t)$. This means $\forall n$, 
\begin{align}
u_0^n&=u^n_M\\
u_{M+1}^n &= u_1^n\\
\end{align}
Let's look at know what happen at $i=1$ and $i=M$:
\begin{align}
i=1 , \quad u_{1}^{n+1} &= u_{1}^n-\gamma u_{2}^n + \gamma u_{0}^n \\
&= u_{1}^n-\gamma u_{2}^n + \gamma u_{M}^n \\
i=M, \quad u_{M}^{n+1} &= u_{M}^n-\gamma u_{M+1}^n + \gamma u_{M-1}^n \\
 &= u_{M}^n-\gamma u_{1}^n + \gamma u_{M-1}^n \\
\end{align}
Writting the above in matrix form, you have for $n\in \{1,\dots, N\}$ :
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{U}^{n+1} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{U}^{n}
\end{equation}
Which can rewritten as for $M=5$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1^{n+1}\\ 
u_2^{n+1}\\ 
u_3^{n+1}\\ 
u_4^{n+1}\\ 
u_5^{n+1}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 &1  &-\gamma  &0  &0  &\gamma  \\ 
 &\gamma  &1  &-\gamma  &0  &0  \\ 
 &0  &\gamma  &1  &-\gamma   &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &\gamma  &1  &-\gamma   \\
 &-\gamma  &0  &0  &\gamma  &1   \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
u_1^n\\ 
u_2^n\\ 
u_3^n\\ 
u_4^n\\ 
u_5^n\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Just one more question. With this discretization, is it true that $u_1=u_M$?

Comment: Yes. I think in last row I have a coefficient of 1 for $u_1$. So that $ u_{M}^{n+1} = u_{1}^n-\gamma u_{2}^n + \gamma u_{M-1}^n $

Comment: Sorry  but I do not agree, because that expression does not imply that $u_{M}=u_1$. Moreover, in your matrix the $1$ should be in entry (m,m), as the scheme told us

Comment: @VoB: Sorry I was not thinking straight on this one. I made some modifications at my initial post. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: so, the periodicity is imposed by using a value outside of the domain, i.e. $u_0$, not imposing that the first and last value nodes $u_1,u_M$ are equal, right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99624/discussion-between-vob-and-sesame).